# Controle RTS/DTR C++

Tags: c++, serial

Realizando uma integração de um dispositivo RS232, encontramos um entrave que está relacionado ao controle de fluxo utilizando o RTS e DTR com o equipamento. Utilizando a função EscapeCommFunction para manipular os sinais nesses pinos, não foi possível estabelecer a comunicação com o aparelho, não tendo resposta ao comando de inicialização de comunicação. Exemplo:

**Inicializando a porta**

```
HANDLE hSerial;
DCB dcbSerialParams = {0};
COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = {0};

hSerial = CreateFile("\\\\.\\COM1", GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING,FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL );

dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_19200;
dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 7;
dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
dcbSerialParams.Parity = EVENPARITY;
dcbSerialParams.fDtrControl = DTR_CONTROL_ENABLE;
dcbSerialParams.fRtsControl = RTS_CONTROL_ENABLE;
SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams);

timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
SetCommTimeouts(hSerial, &timeouts);

EscapeCommFunction(hSerial,CLRDTR);
EscapeCommFunction(hSerial,CLRRTS);
```

**Enviando comando**

```
EscapeCommFunction(hSerial,SETRTS)

DWORD bytes_written, total_bytes_written = 0;

if(!WriteFile(hSerial, bytes_to_send, sizeof(bytes_to_send), &bytes_written, NULL))
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Erro\n");
    CloseHandle(hSerial);
    return 1;
}
fprintf(stderr, "%d bytes escritos...", bytes_written);
EscapeCommFunction(hSerial,CLRRTS);
```

**Visualizando respostas**

```
char buffer[32];
DWORD  bytes_read;

//loop infinito de leitura
while(true){
    EscapeCommFunction(hSerial,SETDTR)
    ReadFile(hSerial, buffer, sizeof(buffer), &bytes_read, NULL);
    if (bytes_read){
        fprintf(stderr, "Número de bytes lidos %d\n",bytes_read);
    }
    EscapeCommFunction(hSerial,CLRDTR)
}
```

Não há qualquer resposta por parte do equipamento, porém, sabemos que o comando utilizado não apresenta erros, pois o fabricante disponibiliza um software que executa a mesma comunicação porém não exportando os dados, servindo apenas pra visualização, e fazendo um *spy* na porta durante essa comunicação, verificamos a integridade dos comandos.

Existe algo que poderia estar passando em branco nesse controle ou outra forma de ser realizado?

Answer (score 0):

Prezado Paulo,

usei muito a serial em Windows 98 -- há milhares de anos atrás, portanto. Muita coisa poderá ter mudado.

O que posso dizer daquela experiência é que a manipulação da serial em Windows é enormemente mais complexa do que em Linux. Além disso, muita coisa das chamadas da API Win32 não funciona segundo a documentação, e deve ser experimentado ponto a ponto.

Um ponto importante é fazer o que chamo de **programação paranoica**. Ou seja: testar cada chamada de função, e chamar o correspondente `GetLastError()` quando a chamada gerar erro.

Em seu caso, no bloco *Inicializando a porta*, eu testaria se a chamada a `CreateFile()` gerou um handle válido. Em seguida, confirmaria que as chamadas a `EscapeCommFunction()` geraram erros.

É sempre importante chamar `GetLastError()` depois de cada problema, para tentar entender o que houve.

De modo similar nos outros blocos: cada chamada deve ser testada quanto a erro, e `GetLastError()` deve ser consultado para se entender o que houve.

Qual tutorial você está usando para montar seu programa ? É importante localizar um bom tutorial como base -- naturalmente, testando-o bastante, para ver se funciona com seus equipamentos.

Tentando relembrar como eu usava a serial, acredito que seu código talvez esteja mais simples do que aquele que eu acabei usando na prática. Examinando a lista de funções de comunicação na página [Communications Functions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/devio/communications-functions), acredito que eu fazia uso de várias outras funções, como `BuildCommDCB()`, SetCommConfig() e talvez `WaitCommEvent()`.

O código funcionava bem, na ocasião -- e eu me comunicava com sucesso com centrais telefônicas que não entendiam RS-232 da mesma forma que a Microsoft...

São coisas de 20 anos atrás, mas tentarei localizar o código em algum lugar de minhas tralhas.